# setInterval to fade in then fade out pure javascript no jquery or css

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval, fade

I am trying to implement a fade in/fade out feature that runs on a button click depending if some data was changed. I am using angular but the ngAnimate I could not get to work so I want to do it with pure js. What I currently have will flash the text for a second, then do nothing. This is inside my controller.

```
var warningText = document.getElementById('warningText');
warningText.style.display = 'inline'
$scope.warningText = "Warning: No Data was updated.";
var op = 0.0;
var fadeIn = setInterval(function() {
    if (op >= 1) {
        clearInterval(fadeIn);
        fadeOut(op);
    }
    warningText.style.opacity = op;
    op += op * 0.1;
}, 50);
var fadeOut = function(op) {
    setInterval(function() {
        if (op <= 0.1) {
            clearInterval(fadeOut);
            warningText.style.display = 'none';
        }
        warningText.style.opacity = op;
        op -= op * 0.1;
    }, 50);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried CSS3 animations/transitions?

Comment: Won't `op * 0.1` always equal zero?

Comment: I think it should be `op += 0.1` and `op -=  0.1` instead

Comment: Changing it to += 1 and -+ 1 made the fade work, but it only triggers once. I did try CSS3 animations, but they would not work correctly, and my boss said to not use them.

Comment: might be because you're setting the `display` to `none` in the `fadeOut` and not setting it back to to `block` in `fadeIn` function

Comment: every time the button is clicked, I am telling it to display inline, until the fadeout function tells it to display none

Comment: But hy should you bother setting display to none when the next thing you do is to raise the opacity again? Seems like an action you can just skip.

Comment: Well I only want it to trigger once. If the data hasnt changed, fade in the warning text, then fade it out once. If it did change, do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of `op` is wrong as that will always be zero. Secondly the second function does not return the value from `setInterval`, so you'll never be able to clear that interval.

Here is how you could do it with just one interval, where the sign of the increments to the opacity is reversed every time the boundary value is reached:

```js
var warningText = document.getElementById('warningText');

function flickerMessage(msg) {
    var op = 0.1;
    var increment = +0.1;
    warningText.textContent = msg;
    warningText.style.opacity = 0;
    warningText.style.display = 'inline';

    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        op += increment;
        warningText.style.opacity = op;
        if (op >= 1) increment = -increment;
        if (op <= 0) {
            warningText.style.display = 'none';
            clearInterval(timer); // end
        }
    }, 50);
}

flickerMessage('Warning you');
```

```html
<div id="warningText" style="display:none; opacity: 0">warning text</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: How would I make this only fade in, then fade out and hide #warningText?

Comment: What is the initial CSS of this element? So you don't want an eternal on/off, just once?

Comment: Initially I do not show it at all. I have it set to a scope variable of an empty string, and then when I need the fade to trigger I give it text on $scope.warningText. Yeah, I just want it to fade in, fade out, and be done. If I were able to use jquery, it would be easy. Not sure why I am so hung up on it.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Not sure why it took me so long to figure it out.